# User permission check in Aggregate Root or Application Service?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

In my project, there is a concept of user A sending a `FriendRequest` to user B. In a simplified version, the request looks like this:

```
class FriendRequest 
{
     long Id;
     int UserId;
     int OtherUserId;
     string Message;
}
```

In the `Accept` method, I need to check whether the current authenticated user equals the `OtherUserId` in the `FriendRequest`. The `currentAuthenticatedUserId` is passed from the controller down to the application service. Now, the question comes that whether I should do the check in the application service or in the `FriendRequest` aggregate root.

```
//In application service code:
if(currentAuthenticatedUserId !=friendRequest.OtherUserId)
{
    throw new FriendRequestException("Can only accept friend requests sent to you");
}
friendRequest.Accept();
```

vs.

```
//In application service, but we are not checking it here.
friendRequest.Accept(currentAuthenticatedUserId); //The check is done inside `FriendRequest` and the exception is also thrown there.
```

Comment: This post https://medium.com/p/671f7a5596ac talk about authorization and authentication in DDD. Discloser: I'm the author

Comment: @martinezdelariva Thanks. It lightened me up a bit. I'd go with the check inside application services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Access control is one of the main responsibilities of application services.**

So check the user ID in the app service, not in the entity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, especially the mention of `access control`. It is better than `user permission` I came up with. The clear-cut rule is simple to follow and makes sense to me. I knew that I should put business rules inside aggregate roots but I had a hard time deciding whether access control is business rule or not because it looks really important and also shows up in the ubiquitous language.

Comment: In the general case, "check the user ID in the app service" describes more likely the authentication process, not a permission check.
Some permissions check seem complex enough to warrant their presence inside the aggregate. Would you suggest ACL should be passed along commands to let the aggregate decide?

Answer (score 1):

```
friendRequest.Accept(...)
```

What does it mean in the domain terms? The request accepts itself or what does it accept? I believe, you need to expand your ubiquitous language with more verbs that correlate to nouns.

As an example, I might think of "a person can accept a friend request that was sent by another person". In this case you would have a `person.Accept(friendRequest)`. It will then be the service responsibility to fetch the `Person` based on the current authentication details.

Comment: I can understand what you are suggesting. It is more OOP. I don't have any encapsulation of a user right now. I simply pass around `userId`. In my application, almost everything is done by a user, almost in any bounded context. Do I have a `User` model for each bounded context?